# Como colocar informações nos atributos de um objeto usando ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Criei uma Classe `Cliente` com atributos nome,idade,endereco,cpf. E na classe main eu fui fazer uma `ArrayList` do tipo `Cliente`, dessa forma `ArrayList Cliente<String> = new ArrayList<>();` no intuito de criar um vetor que vai crescendo o tamanho enquanto eu for cadastrando Clientes.

Porém, como faço para colocar as informações nos atributos do `Cliente` de um determinado indice do `ArrayList`?

Por exemplo, se eu tiver no indice zero, eu queria fazer algo do tipo  `Cliente.nome.add("Joao");`

E assim eu ia atribuindo os valores da mesma maneira para os atributos idade,endereco,cpf.

Tem alguma maneira de eu fazer isso? Porque nos tutoriais de como fazer um cadastro que vi só colocavam tipo `Cliente.add("Joao");` e eu não queria colocar somente nome, já que tenho vários atributos para cadastrar.

A Classe que criei foi tipo essa :

```
public abstract class Pessoa {
    private String nome,sexo,cpf,endereco,email,dataNascimento;
    private int telefone;

    public String getSexo() {
        return sexo;
    }

    public void setSexo(String sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getDataNascimento() {
        return dataNascimento;
    }

    public void setDataNascimento(String dataNascimento) {
        this.dataNascimento = dataNascimento;
    }

    public int getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public void setTelefone(int telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }




    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

   public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }


}
```

E na Classe principal eu queria acessar os meus Atributos só que usando ArryList tipo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       ArrayList<String> Cliente = new ArrayList<>();
       Cliente.nome.add("Joao"); 
       Obs : Esta linha acima que fiz está errada porque eu nao sei como acessar esses atributos.
    }
```

Comment: Alias, não se trata bem de uma duvida sobre a api grafica, mas mesmo assim você poderia adicionar um **[mcve]** pois ele ajuda a compreender melhor o problema.

Comment: Assim,mano. Nem precisava ser no Swing nao, eu queria saber apenas como acessava os atributos de um determinado indice de uma ArrayList. A Classe que criei foi apenas aquela básica que citei ali em cima, porem eu não sei como acessar os atributos de uma ArrayList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você quer preencher objetos do tipo Cliente no arraylist e da forma como ele está não vai dar certo, pelo simples fato de seu Arraylist ser de strings. Você deve criar uma classe `Cliente` ou tornar essa classe Pessoa não abstrata e criar um ArrayList de Pessoa.

## Forma 1

Crie a classe Cliente que estenda dessa classe Pessoa, se Cliente for um tipo de Pessoa e esta ultima classe precisar ser mesmo abstrata:

```
public class Cliente extends Pessoa {

    // construtores, getters, setters e atributos exclusivos da classe

}
```

E seu arraylist ficaria desta forma:

```
ArrayList<Pessoa> cliente = new ArrayList<>();
```

E para adicionar os objetos você utiliza o método `add()`:

```
cliente.add(new Cliente());
```

---

## Forma 2

Fazer a classe Pessoa deixar de ser abstrata e preencher o ArrayList com instancias dela propria:

```
ArrayList<Pessoa> cliente = new ArrayList<>();

...

cliente.add(new Pessoa());
```

Lembrando que você acessa objetos de um arraylist através do método [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-), passando o indice a ser acessado.

Óbvio que isso é puramente ilustrativo, seguindo a lógica desse tipo de objeto, o que imagino ser correto é ter um construtor já iniciando os atributos principais e não se permitindo criar um objeto do tipo Pessoa ou Cliente "vazio".

E também se atente ao fato de que criar um ArrayList do tipo Pessoa apenas não significa que ele será todo preenchido por objetos desse tipo em sua inicialização, você precisa criar os objetos e adicionar um por um, isso é apenas uma forma de restringir que aquela lista possua apenas um determinado tipo.

Answer (score 2):

O problema está em usar um ArrayList de String, não de clientes.
Comece criando uma lista de clientes...

```
ArrayList<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<>();
```

Seria uma boa ideia também criar um construtor para os atributos que você quer utilizar, por exemplo, nome e telefone.

```
Cliente(String nome, int telefone){
  // construtor
  }
```

Dessa forma fica mais fácil adicionar à lista apenas instanciando um novo objeto

```
clientes.add(new Cliente("Fulano", 12345678);
```

*PS: cuidado com `int` para telefones. Dependendo da linguagem, pode não caber o dado completo. Um celular com DDD possui 11 dígitos e int em Java possui 32 bits, ou um valor máximo de 4294967296 (se for `unsigned`, ou seja, não aceitar valores negativos). O melhor é usar `long`.*